# How to insert bookmarks and bookmark values from the table in the existing template repeatedly (in loop) using Aspose.Words in.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspose, aspose.words

I try to insert bookmarks and bookmark values from the table in the existing template repeatedly (in loop) using Aspose.Words in.Net using Aspose.Words

Answer (score 1):

@Manil,

You can meet this requirement by using the **Mail Merge with Regions** feature of 'Aspose.Words for .NET' API. For example, please see [these sample input/output Word documents](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2zxyb29worysd1x/Documents.zip?dl=0) and try running the following code:

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTable();
Document doc = new Document("E:\\temp\\TableStart.docx");
doc.MailMerge.FieldMergingCallback = new HandleMergeField();
doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(dt);
doc.Save("E:\\Temp\\19.8.docx");
```

---

```
private static DataTable GetDataTable()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("tbl");

    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mf1"));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mf2"));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mf3"));

    DataRow dataRow;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        dataRow[0] = "Some Text " + i;
        dataRow[1] = "Some Bookmaked Text " + i;
        dataRow[2] = "Again Some Text " + i;
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    return dataTable;
}

public class HandleMergeField : IFieldMergingCallback
{
    void IFieldMergingCallback.FieldMerging(FieldMergingArgs e)
    {
        if (e.FieldName.Equals("mf2"))
        {
            DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(e.Document);
            builder.MoveToMergeField(e.FieldName);
            builder.Font.Color = Color.Red;

            builder.StartBookmark("bm_" + e.RecordIndex);
            builder.Write(e.FieldValue.ToString());
            builder.EndBookmark("bm_" + e.RecordIndex);
        }
    }

    void IFieldMergingCallback.ImageFieldMerging(ImageFieldMergingArgs args)
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.